# Why does my object (rectangle) flickers when I move my image?

Tags: javascript

When I move my object from the left to the right my rectangle (where I am supposed to put the high score and lives) flickers? How can I fix this? I have the same problem when I use a fillText, the text flickers each time I go to the left or right with my paddle.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mijnCanvas");
var mijnObject = canvas.getContext("2d");

var afbeelding = new Image();
var balkX = (canvas.width/2)-50;
var balkY = canvas.height-100;

function makenBalkKort() {
    mijnObject.drawImage(afbeelding, balkX, balkY, afbeelding.width, afbeelding.height);
}
afbeelding.src = "Afbeeldingen/BrickSmasher_Balk_Kort.png";

function tekenenObjecten() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    makenBalkKort();
    drawFrame();
}
setInterval(tekenenObjecten, 20);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function LinksOfRechts() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(balkX, balkY, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var balkNaarX = 15;
    var code = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if(code == 37) {
        if(balkX > 0) {
            balkX -= balkNaarX;
        }
    }
    else if(code == 39) {
        if(balkX < canvas.width-afbeelding.width) {
            balkX += balkNaarX;
        }
    }
    mijnObject.drawImage(afbeelding, balkX, balkY, afbeelding.width, afbeelding.height);
});

function drawFrame() {
        mijnObject.beginPath();
        mijnObject.fillStyle = "#000000";
        mijnObject.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        mijnObject.rect(0, 750, canvas.width, 50);
        mijnObject.fill();
        mijnObject.stroke();
        mijnObject.closePath();     
}
```

Here is my image:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest putting this in a JSFiddle or similar site to show the actual example.

Comment: and the image (Afbeeldingen/BrickSmasher_Balk_Kort.png)  isn't coming through

Comment: @dangel My bad, I forgot the put the image online... For the JSFiddle, I'm still new here and I really don't know how to work with all those things, but if you upload the image like it says in the code, everything will work (just that flickering thing) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is flickering because you're clearing a large rectangle in your `keydown` event handler, and part of this covers the bottom area. There is then a delay of up to 20 milliseconds before the function that redraws the whole board is queued.

A simple, but dirty fix would be to adjust the area being cleared in the `keydown` handler to only cover the image area:

```
mijnObject.clearRect(balkX, balkY, afbeelding.width, afbeelding.height);
```

However, a better solution would be to avoid making any changes to the canvas in any event handlers; that is, to remove the `clearRect` and `drawImage` calls from the event handler. To ensure that the canvas refreshes as soon as possible with the updated state, you can then use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval` to call the `tekenenObjecten` function:

```
function tekenenObjecten() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    makenBalkKort();
    drawFrame();
    requestAnimationFrame(tekenenObjecten);
}

requestAnimationFrame(tekenenObjecten);
```

Comment: I always thought that you have to clear the rectangle. Like I have a power-up that when you hit the brick it becomes long for a couple of seconds and I thought that without the clearRect you will see the long paddle over the short paddle because you didn't delete the short paddle before using the long paddle. You know what I mean?

Comment: @KevinN While you *can* clear the rectangle in the event handler to accomplish that, it quickly becomes very complicated to try and handle all such cases. It'll give you plenty of headaches to try and do it like that. Everything becomes much simpler if you let a single function (e.g. `tekenenObjecten`) clear the whole canvas and redraw everything at a short interval. For example, your power-up could set a variable for which paddle image to use on the next redraw, and thus avoid having to redraw in the event handler

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It works ;)